# error while creating a jhipster project on linux

Tags: jhipster

When I m running

> sudo yo jhipster

, I m getting this error at the end of the creation process:

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/userxxx/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Object.fs.openSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:289:15)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:33:29)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:26:44)
    at new Insight (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:26:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js:123:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I have tried :

> chown userxxx /home/userxxx/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml

But this doesn't help.

If I m trying to create my project without sudo, it ends with :

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/userxxx/.npm/each-async/0.1.3'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/userxxx/.npm/each-async/0.1.3']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/userxxx/.npm/each-async/0.1.3',
npm ERR!   parent: 'grunt-svgmin' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-23-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/userxxx/dev/workspace/blankjhipster
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /home/userxxx/.npm/each-async/0.1.3
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/userxxx/.npm/each-async/0.1.3'
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

it appears that the folder 01.1.3 doesn't exits, I have the folder 1.1.0

If anyone knows about this issue...
I m using ubuntu 14.10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you don't need to use `sudo` with jhipster. Please try the following

1. Delete your existing `~/.npm` cache using sudo for one last time: `sudo rm -r /home/userxxx/.npm`
2. This was the last time to use sudo for this task, all the following commands should be run as user `userxxx` without sudo
3. Create your project directory and `cd` into it: `mkdir /home/userxxx/my-jhipster-project && cd /home/userxxx/my-jhipster-project`
4. Generate your project using jhipster: `yo jhipster`